# Should names of "named theorems" be capitalized?

Tags: article-writing

Should names of "named theorems" such as the following be capitalized (a) when being mentioned? (b) when being enunciated (of course the first letter would normally be capitalized in the latter case)?

- Fundamental Theorem of Calculus
- Urysohn's Lemma
- Axiom of Choice
- Intermediate Value Property

It seems to me that such phrases are noun phrases constituting "proper names" and hence should be capitalized, as shown, both when enunciated and when referred to in text.

On the other hand, the house style of the Mathematical Association of America is:

"Do not capitalize ... the names of theorems, e.g., fundamental theorem of calculus, mean-value theorem, Picard’s theorem, etc., in most situations." [https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/General_Editorial_Guidelines.pdf]

Moreover, in at least some books published by the American Mathematical Society, such a name is capitalized, as shown, when enunciated but not capitalized when referred to in text (where, e.g., it would be 'fundamental theorem of calculus').

Comment: You have MAA's guidelines, and you have articulated your own opposing thoughts. Clearly, this is a matter of opinion, is it not? (I wonder if [Academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com) might be a better place for this question.)

Comment: IMO when first mentioning the theorem you should do so, but not after the first introduction. For instance label it as something like **Theorem 1.1 (Hensel's Lemma).** but when referring to it later on, just say either "by Theorem 1.1, ..." or "by Hensel's lemma, ...". My reasoning is that repeated capitalisation of the theorem's name can be distracting. But I agree that this question is not appropriate for MSE.

Comment: I was after rationale for the capitalization style.